# Get a excel dropdown from the cell addreess

Tags: c#, excel-addins

I have  a excel worksheet .There is a drop down columns . I need to get a specific drop down from the cell address .

i get the worksheet from following code

```
             Application application;
             Workbook activeWorkBook;
             Worksheet activeWorkSheet;

             application = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

             activeWorkBook = (Workbook)application.ActiveWorkbook;

             activeWorkSheet = activeWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
```

how to get a drop down in a specific cell using cell address in active worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is: Do it manually without VBA. Assuming you know that and you would like to automate the procedure

[Scroll down on this page..](http://software-solutions-online.com/excel-vba-drop-down-lists/)